# RabbitMQ msg_store_transient directory eats all available disk space

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a problem with RabbitMQ 2.8.2 server. 
After one or two days usage I receive Disk Space warning from RabbitMQ and the only solution I found is to clear directory **/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@linux-3blg/msg_store_transient** and restart RabbitMQ. I use rather huge messages in my program 1-50MB may be problem is there, but I really need stability. 
Does anybody knows the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This means that messages are not being acknowledged and consumed. It might help to make use of the Time-To-Live Extensions. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl and set an expiration for messages.